# error to access DB from a user of the database

Tags: php, mysql

First of all, sorry if I dont make the question correctly because it's my first question here

I am developing a simple web portal to display some records that I create myself in Excel. To display the records in a table, I use a form with jQuery to update the information in some fields. The problem is that locally I can access the database and the label updates automatically when I select one company or another. However, when I upload it to the Plesk panel, it shows the error: Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'MyIP' (using password: YES).

I've tried using localhost, localhost:port, and finally the IP address, but I can't get it to update. What I find strange is that it can query the database without any problem to retrieve the companies, but the jQuery query is denied.

My index:

```
<?php


    
    $host = 'myIP';
    $database = 'registro_logs';
    $user = 'adminlog';
    $password = 'miContraseña';
    
    
    /*
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'registro_logs';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '';
    */
    
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // recordar la variable de sesion
    session_start();


    //validar que se cree una variable de sesion al pasar por login
    $correo = $_SESSION['correo'];
    $usuario = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    if (!isset($correo)) {
        header("location:form_login.php");
    }

    $result = null;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['entidad']) && isset($_POST['fecha_inicio']) && isset($_POST['fecha_fin'])) {
        $fecha_inicio = $_POST['fecha_inicio'];
        $fecha_fin = $_POST['fecha_fin'];
        $empresa = $_POST['entidad'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM registro WHERE fecha_conexion BETWEEN ? AND ? AND entidad=?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin,$empresa);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    $consultaEmpresas = "SELECT DISTINCT entidad FROM registro";
    $resultado_empresas = mysqli_query($conn, $consultaEmpresas);
    $miau = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_empresas);


    $conn->close();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <title>Registro Logs</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #142c3c;
        }

        label {
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    
    <?php $fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d"); ?>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row mt-5 ">
            <div class="col-8 mx-auto" >
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label for="entidad" class="form-label">Empresa</label>
                        <select class="form-select" name="entidad" id="entidad">
                            <option value="">Seleccione empresa</option>
                            <?php
                                while ($row = $resultado_empresas->fetch_array()) {

                                    ?><option value="<?php echo $empresa = $row['entidad']; ?>"><?php echo $empresa = $row['entidad']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }    
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label for="usuario" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
                        <select class="form-select" name="usuario" id="usuario"> 
                            <option value="*">Todos</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label for="fecha_inicio">Fecha inicio</label>
                        <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" min="2021-01-01" max='<?php echo $fecha_actual ?>' class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-2">
                        <label for="fecha_fin">Fecha fin</label>
                        <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin" min="2021-01-01" max='<?php echo $fecha_actual ?>' class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Filtrar" onclick="filtrarDatos()">
                    <a href="cerrar_sesion.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cerrar sesión</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8">
                <p class="text-white f-600" id="num_registros"></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="" id="tablaResultados">
            
        </div>
        
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="d-none" id="paginacion">
                    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="cambiarPagina(-1)">Anterior</button>
                    <span class="text-white" id="pagina_actual">1</span>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" onclick="cambiarPagina(1)">Siguiente</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



    </div>

    <script>
        

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#entidad').change(function() {
                var entidadSeleccionada = $(this).val();
                console.log(entidadSeleccionada)
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'obtener_usuarios.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: { entidad: entidadSeleccionada },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $('#usuario').empty();  // Limpiamos las opciones existentes
                        $('#usuario').append('<option value="*">Todos</option>');
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            
                            $('#usuario').append('<option value="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                            
                        });
                    }

                });
            });
        });


        let paginaActual = 1;
        const registrosPorPagina = 5;

        function filtrarDatos() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'filtrar_datos.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    empresa: $('#entidad').val(),
                    usuario: $('#usuario').val(),
                    fechaInicio: $('#fecha_inicio').val(),
                    fechaFinal: $('#fecha_fin').val(),
                    pagina: paginaActual,
                    cantidad: registrosPorPagina
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    let tabla = '<div class="row mt-4 justify-content-center"><div class="col-8 mx-auto"><table class="table table-striped">';
                    tabla += '<thead><tr><th>Entidad</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Email</th><th>Fecha de Conexión</th><th>Hora de Conexión</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
                    $('#paginacion').removeClass('d-none').addClass('d-block');
                    data.forEach(row => {
                        tabla += '<tr>';
                        tabla += '<td>' + row.entidad + '</td>';
                        tabla += '<td>' + row.nombre + '</td>';
                        tabla += '<td>' + row.email + '</td>';
                        tabla += '<td>' + row.fecha_conexion + '</td>';
                        tabla += '<td>' + row.hora_conexion + '</td>';
                        tabla += '</tr>';
                    });

                    tabla += '</tbody></table></div></div>';
                    $('#tablaResultados').html(tabla);
                    document.getElementById('num_registros').textContent = "Registros mostrados: " + data.length;
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.error("Hubo un error: ", error);
                }
            });
        }

        function cambiarPagina(cambio) {
            paginaActual += cambio;
            // Agregar validación para que la página actual no sea menor que 1
            if (paginaActual < 1) paginaActual = 1;
                $('#pagina_actual').text(paginaActual);
            filtrarDatos();
        }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the .php where I get the users from the companies:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "registro_logs";

    // Conexión a la base de datos
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    // Verificar conexión
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Obtener la empresa desde la petición POST
    if (isset($_POST['entidad'])) { 
        
        $campo =  $_POST['entidad'];
    } else {
        //echo "hola2";
        $campo = null;
    }


    // Preparar la consulta SQL para obtener los usuarios de la empresa seleccionada
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT nombre FROM registro WHERE entidad = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $campo);

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $usuarios = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $usuarios[] = $row['nombre'];
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();

    // Devolver la lista de usuarios en formato JSON
    echo json_encode($usuarios, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Comment: You have the database credentials explicitly stored in both files - so the most likely explanation is that you simply forget to modify those in the second file accordingly.

Comment: Usually one would put such credentials into a file on their own - and then _include_ that file, wherever those credentials are needed.